# Avoid form to hang in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I would like to know what method you suggest to avoid my form to hang while executing a stored procedure. See my attached code. I am collecting data from Twitter via the Stream API and while executing the sproc the form hangs.
Is using the BackgroundWorker the best method to avoid the form from hanging? Could you give me an example how implement this is in my code.

```
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub btnDB_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDB.Click
        Dim url As String = "https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?track=twitter"
        Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
        request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("username", "pwd")
        Dim WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        Dim encode As Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")
        Dim responseStrem = New StreamReader(WebResponse.GetResponseStream(), encode)




        While Not responseStrem.EndOfStream
            'Console.WriteLine(responseStrem.ReadLine());

            Dim json As String = responseStrem.ReadLine()
            If json.Length <> 0 Then
                ParseJson(json)
            End If
        End While
    End Sub

    Private Sub ParseJson(ByVal Json As String)

        Dim connectionstring As String = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=db_twitter_stream;User ID=sa;Password=xxx"
        Dim counter As Integer = 0
        Dim conn As New SqlConnection(connectionstring)
        conn.Open()
        Dim o As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)

        Dim tweet As String = o("text")
        Dim source As String = o("source")
        Dim created_at As String = o("created_at")

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("dbo.prc_tweets", conn)
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@tweet", tweet))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@source", source))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@created_at", created_at))

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        counter = counter + 1
        lblCount.Text = counter.ToString()



        conn.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnQuit_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnQuit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub



End Class
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398490/how-to-make-a-very-simple-asynchronous-method-call-in-vb-net

Answer (score 0):

Your form hangs because you are running the code in the main thread. The main thread is responsible for giving response to mouse clicks, showing output and to loop for taking input. But once u make the main thread indulge into something else, It can no longer run all its tasks while it executes your code, this makes it look like that your form is stuck. You need to create another thread for bigger tasks. You need to use thread pools or more procedures from System.Threading class. Create a sub like Private Sub and name it something and put all your hectic code in it and end the sub with End Sub. And then make a thread variable and address it to that Sub. `Dim variable As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf yoursubnamehere)`. Then set its properties like priority etc. Then `threadvariable.Start()` . Problem solved :)
You can also use backgroundworker too if it is more convenient to you.