# Invoke web service method without waiting for it to finish

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have ASP.NET 2010 (VB.NET) web-service having a method "Method1".
I need to invoke that method from Windows application (VB.NET 2010) without waiting for the method to end execution, also do not need to get the return value of the method. Just need to invoke it and that's all.

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: I suggest using threads

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a very simple asynchronous method call in vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398490/how-to-make-a-very-simple-asynchronous-method-call-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you edit your question giving more information about your needs, maybe some code that you're pretending to use, it should be easy to help you.

So, without that information I can assume that maybe investing about asynchronous methods should be helpful for you. It's not just about put async keyword...

You can find more information from here:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5179579a-492b-4aad-babe-fdef854b68b3/c-50-calling-a-method-without-requiring-to-wait-for-it-to-finish-nor-its-results?forum=csharpgeneral

Hope to be useful... Greetings.

Comment: Yes, I need to call web-service method asynchronously. What code is needed in the server side, and what in the client side.